# Run time linking for APIs and "-ldllname" compiler option

Tags: c, winapi, dll, linker

I used `Loadlibrary` and `Getprocaddress` to link some of the WinApis for runtime linking. It works fine, as expected.

But for some Apis I just used `-ldllname` as the compiler option. The same option gives linker error for some APIs, and needs the dll to be loaded.

Is there any particular difference in this, that is some particular APIs need runtime linking and other APIs will work with `-ldllname` option?? How to clasify APIs of these kind?

> Update: What I observed is the APIs supporting UNICODE and ANSI i.e.,
>   The API which is suffixed with "W" and "A" , get resolved with static
>   linking itself? Am I correct? Correct me if I am wrong!
>
> why some APIs need Run time linking and others get resolved with Static
>   linking itself(-l option)? Any reason for this?

Comment: In compiler options have you specified directory where the library exists? What error do you get?

Comment: yes I specified the library path. this happens only for some APIs and for other the -l option works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used Loadlibrary

That would be an example of taking an implicit dependency on a DLL.  LoadLibrary is a function that's exported by kernel32.dll, a Windows api DLL.  It actually exists in two versions, LoadLibraryA and LoadLibraryW.  Respectively the non-Unicode and the Unicode version of the function.  You'll get one or the other, depending on whether you have the UNICODE macro #defined when you compile.

So that's the exact opposite of dynamically linking an export with GetProcAddress, you must tell the linker that your program has a dependency on kernel32 with the `-l` option.  And at runtime the DLL automatically gets loaded before your own code starts running.

Having an implicit dependency on operating system DLLs is quite normal.  And unavoidable, you can never dynamically link kernel32.dll, that would be a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: Technically no, it is merely "quite normal", you certainly can dynamically load operating system DLLs.  And that's a very normal thing to do if the api function is only available in later versions of the OS.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If possible can you explain me why som APIs need Run time linking and others get resolved with Static linking itself(-l option)? sorry for troubling more..

Comment: This is almost never necessary and you ought to use this technique sparingly.  Getting the function pointer declaration wrong is a major source of bugs.  Except in the corner case of having a use for a function that might not be available on the user's machine.  And, of course, being able to do without it if you find out that the function isn't available.  Which is not common.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially what you described. I'll skip non-Windows here but there it's essentially similar).

So, there are two different cases:

**Compile time (static) linking:** Code includes declarations for all functions, classes, etc. but no bodies. You'll have to provide the proper library file on compile time (e.g. through `-ldllname`):

```
void sayHello(void); // the declaration might be a bit more complicated, e.g. adding a calling convention or dllimport/dllexport, etc.
```

**Runtime (dynamic) linking:** Code includes minimal function bodies essentially loading libraries and retrieving addresses (through the functions you named):

```
HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("hello.dll"); // loading happening somewhere once

void sayHello(void) {
    myfnproc call = GetProcAddress(lib, "sayHello");
    call(); // actual call
}

FreeLibrary(lib); // unloading happening somewhere else
```

While the runtime approach is more complicated, it has one big advantage: You're able to handle the missing library. E.g. if the user is lacking some library, you can tell him where to download it (or even download it yourself) and the linked code can easily be replaced (e.g. plugin functionality). With static linking you're out of luck: The program won't run if dependencies are missing.

Comment: thanks for your answer (+1). But my doubt here is why some APIs need dll linking and other APIs get solved with Static linking itself?

Comment: It's a design choice. E.g. for OpenGL/GLEW its possible that not all functions might be provided by the local implementation, so dynamic linking is used to skip stuff not being available.

Comment: Mario please have a look at the updated part of my question. Am I right in that?